# how to move previous page and show values in fields?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i make two web page,i want to get data from first page on second page,if user click edit message then move first page and show the entered data of user,here is my code:

first.php

```
    <h1>Compose Message</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=MURL?>/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> 
    <script src="//ticket_inspector_new.com/js/tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>  
    <form action="" method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
    <table class="form">
    <tr class="heading">
        <th style="width: 25%;">Recipients</th>
        <th style="width: 75%;">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="campaigns">Campaigns</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="events[]" multiple size="10" >
            <?
            $select = sprintf ("SELECT event_id,event_name
                            FROM `events`
                            WHERE (`user_id` = '%s') order by event_name",
                            $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->real_escape_string ($_SESSION['user_id']));

            $res = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($select) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
            if ($res->num_rows > 0)
            {

                while($row = $res->fetch_assoc ())
                {

            ?>
              <option value="<?=$row['event_id']?>"><?=$row['event_name']?></option>
            <?
                }
            }
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:95px;">
            <label for="fromdate">Registrants From</label>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left:10px;">
            <input name="fromdate" type="text" value="" class="calendar time" id="fromdate" size="30" />
            <label for="todate">To</label>
            <input name="todate" type="text" value="" class="calendar time" id="todate" size="30" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="upload">Upload CSV</label>
            <span class="helptip">
                Select CSV file for upload.
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="uploadcsv" type="file" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="heading">
        <th style="width: 25%;">Message</th>
        <th style="width: 75%;">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="description">Description(optional)</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="description" type="text" value="" id="description" size="35" />
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="subject" type="text" value="" id="subject" size="35" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="fromname">From Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="fromname" type="text" value="" id="fromname" size="27" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="replyto">Reply To</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="replyto" type="text" value="" id="replyto" size="27" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="senddatetime">Send Date/Time</label>
            <span class="helptip">
                Click the calender to select the date you wish ans select time zone from select box.
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="senddatetime" type="text" value="" class="calendar time" id="senddatetime" size="30" />
            <select name="timezone" id="timezone">
                    <option value="Pacific/Honolulu">Hawaii-Aleutian Time (Honolulu, no DST)

</option><option value="America/Anchorage">Alaska Time (Anchorage)</option><option value="America/Los_Angeles" 

selected="selected">Pacific Time (Los Angeles)</option><option value="America/Denver">Mountain Time (Denver)</option><option 

value="America/Phoenix">Mountain Time (Phoenix, no DST)</option><option value="America/Chicago">Central Time (Chicago)

</option><option value="America/Regina">Central Time (Regina, no DST)</option><option value="America/New_York">Eastern Time 

(New York)</option><option value="America/Halifax">Atlantic Time (Halifax)</option>
                </select>
            <script>
            var list = document.getElementById('timezone');        
            var selval = "0";        
            for(var i = 0; i < list.options.length; ++i)                
            {
                if(list.options[i].value==selval)
                {
                    list.options[i].selected = true;        
                    i=list.options.length;
                }   
            }
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <textarea name="message" class="ckeditor" id="message" cols="90" rows="15" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<table class="form">
<tr class="heading">
        <th style="width:100%; background-color:#C4C4FE; font-size:10px; font-weight:normal;">Emails can take upto 30 minutes to Send.We have zero tolerance for spam messages.Every message sent out is reviewed for spam.Any spam messages sent will result in termination of account.</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
<p class="center_align">
    <input type="submit" class="button arrow" name="submit_skip" value="Continue" />
</p>

</form>
```

and here is my second page:

```
<h1>Confirm Message</h1>
<? 
$recepients=0;
$count=count($_POST['events']);
  ?>

<input type="button" class="button edit" name="submit_skip" value="Edit Message" />
<input type="submit" class="button email" name="submit_email" value="Send Message" />
```

i want when user click on edit massage it moves previous page and values shown in fields
?>

Comment: Did I understand correctly that your problem is that you have ONE FORM in which are 2 BUTTONs 1) "submit message" 2) "go back" ? and you want to get 2) "go back" to get working?

Comment: yes i want when i click go back the previous posted data show in form fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to send form to a two different scripts I suggest that you use 2 forms:

```
<form action="formfilling.php">
  <?php
    //prepare the recived POST to send back:
    foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ){
      if( is_array($_POST[$key]) ){  //if post is array e.g. your events[]
        foreach( $_POST[$key] as $subvalue ){
          echo '<input type="hidden"'
              .' name="'.htmlspecialchars($key).'[]"'
              .' value="'.htmlspecialchars($subvalue).'">'."\n";
        }      
      } else{
        echo '<input type="hidden"'
            .' name="'.htmlspecialchars($key).'"'
            .' value="'.htmlspecialchars($value).'">'."\n";
      }
    }
  ?>
  <input type="submit" class="button edit" name="submit_skip" value="Edit Message" />
</form>

<form action="submitemail.php">
  <?php //possibly show message? ?>
  <input type="submit" class="button email" name="submit_email" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

And then in formfilling check if input is not empty if not => echo its value

```
if( !empty($_POST['inputName']) ) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['inputName']);
```

And for the array something like

```
if( !empty($_POST['inputName']) ){
   foreach( $_POST['inputName'] as $val ){
      //Test if the current option has the value of $val if so:
      echo /*OPTION with SELECTED*/;
   }
}
```

**ALWAYS USE HTML ESCAPING when printing/echoing $_POST/$_GET** 

=> dont trust the users!

=> in PHP there is a `htmlspecialchars()` function

Answer (score 0):

go to the previous page with javascript

```
window.history.go(-1)
```

Comment: but how to attach $_POST with this

Comment: @Arif as in my answer :)